# Scala best way to make uniform crossover operation with permutation list?

Tags: list, scala, permutation, genetic-algorithm

I search the best and the most elegant way to make GA crossover operator in Scala functional (No "for" loop, with only immutable type if possible), for example, with this list:

```
val A = IndexedSeq (5,4,8)
val B = IndexedSeq (3,2,6)
```

I want to make random bitcoin permutation (with `rng.nextBoolean` for example) between each element in my IndexedSeq, and finally I get the two lists A' and B' after permutation of their elements.

Example of execution:

```
rng.nextBoolean <- (true,false,true)
A' = 3,4,6
B' = 5,2,8
```

Thanks.

Comment: Saying _permutations_ you mean randomly swapping elements between lists?

Comment: Can you give an example of the output you're expecting please?

Comment: I add more information on updated question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def crossover[T](a: Seq[T], b: Seq[T], rs: Seq[Boolean]) =
  (a, b, rs).zipped.map((x, y, z) => if (z) Seq(x, y) else Seq(y, x)).transpose
```

Use with Booleans as third argument:

```
scala> val Seq(a1, b1) = crossover(A, B, List(true, false, true))
a1: Seq[Int] = Vector(5, 2, 8)
b1: Seq[Int] = Vector(3, 4, 6)
```

If you want it with a default sequence of Booleans, you could provide a default argument like this:

```
def crossover[T](a: Seq[T], b: Seq[T], rs: Seq[Boolean] = { 
                                       val rng = new util.Random
                                       Stream.continually(rng.nextBoolean) }) =
  (a, b, rs).zipped.map((x, y, z) => if (z) Seq(x, y) else Seq(y, x)).transpose
```

Comment: I like your approach because it externalizes the randomness(more functional, side effect free). So you can choose to determine randomness at call side or don't worry and call the method with default parameter.

Comment: Which Scala version are you using? With Scala 2.9.1 it doesn't compile, except you change `crossover[T](a: Seq[T], b: Seq[T], rs: Seq[Boolean] = ...)` to `crossover[T](a: Seq[T], b: Seq[T])(rs: Seq[Boolean] = ...)`.

Comment: @PeterSchmitz Thanks - it turns out my REPL namespace was polluted, which is why it worked for me. Have updated. Default argument is trickier than I thought since you'd need to call it with `crossover(A, B)()` which is a bit ugly.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's a great approach :) Thanks also to other contributors for your answer!

Answer (score 4):

Wow, where's all this code coming from? Here:

```
val (a1, b1) = A zip B map (t => if (util.Random.nextBoolean) t.swap else t) unzip
```

There, that's all.

If you already have a list of random booleans, you can do this:

```
val (a1, b1) = A zip B zip C map { case (t, flag) => if (flag) t.swap else t } unzip
```

Comment: Great! Simple and clear! One more example one should know the scala API by heart.

Answer (score 1):

```
import scala.util.Random

val A = IndexedSeq(5,4,8)
val B = IndexedSeq(3,2,6)

def crossover[T](rng: Random)(a: Seq[T], b: Seq[T]): (Seq[T],Seq[T]) = {
  if (a.isEmpty && b.isEmpty) return (Nil,Nil)
  val (aTailCrossover,bTailCrossover) = crossover(rng)(a.tail,b.tail)
  if (rng.nextBoolean) (b.head +: aTailCrossover, a.head +: bTailCrossover)
    else               (a.head +: aTailCrossover, b.head +: bTailCrossover)
}

println(crossover(new Random)(A,B))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def rndCombi [T] (a: Seq[T], b: Seq[T]): Seq[T] = {
  if (a.size != b.size) sys.error ("sizes don't match: a:" + a.size +  " != b: " + b.size) 
  val rnd = util.Random 
  val max = (math.pow (2, a.size)).toInt
  val r = rnd.nextInt (max)

  def pick (a: Seq[T], b: Seq[T], r: Int) : List[T] = {
    if (a.size == 0) Nil else 
    if (r % 2 == 0) a.head :: pick (a.tail , b.tail, r/2) else 
    b.head :: pick (a.tail , b.tail, r/2)
  }

  // print all combinations for testing:
  // (0 until max).map (i => println (pick (a, b, i).mkString ("-")))

  pick (a, b, r).toSeq
}
// I choosed different values for easy testing:
val a = IndexedSeq (7, 8, 9)
val b = IndexedSeq (1, 2, 3)

println (rndCombi (a, b).mkString (" "))
println (rndCombi (a, b.tail).mkString (" "))
```

Initializing util.Random each time is of course not very clever, if done frequently. So for production code you would rearrange the code.

If you don't restrict the input to 2 sequences, it get's more interesting. Here we go:

```
def rndCombi [T] (s: Seq[Seq[T]]): Seq[T] = {

  val outer = s.size 
  val inner = s(0).size 
  val rnd = util.Random 
  val max = (math.pow (outer, inner)).toInt
  val r = rnd.nextInt (max)

  def pick (s: Seq[Seq[T]], r: Int, pos: Int = 0) : List[T] =
    if (pos == inner) Nil 
    else s(r % inner)(pos) :: pick (s, r/inner, pos + 1) 

  // print all combinations for testing:
  (0 until max).map (i => println (pick (s, i).mkString ("-")))  
  println ()
  pick (s, r).toSeq
}

val a = IndexedSeq (1, 2, 3)
val b = IndexedSeq (4, 5, 6)
val c = IndexedSeq (7, 8, 9)

println (rndCombi (Seq (a, b, c)).mkString (" "))
```

The second solution can, of course, be used for 2 sequences as well.