# Return all combinations for nested lists

Tags: scala

I have the following data structure

```
val list = List(1,2,
List(3,4),
List(5,6,7)
)
```

I want to get this as a result

```
List(
List(1,2,3,5), List(1,2,3,6), List(1,2,3,7),
List(1,2,4,5), List(1,2,4,6), List(1,2,4,7)
)
```

Number of sub-lists in the input and number of elements in them can vary

P.S.

I'm trying to use this as a first step

```
list.map{
  case x => List(x)
  case list:List => list
}
```

and some for comprehension, but it won't work because I don't know how many elements each sublist of the result will have

Comment: Simplifying my previous comments, when you say combinations you mean all of the elements of the main list, plus one element from each of the sublists joined together? Or is it something different?

Comment: Agree, the description is not very clear, I'll edit it a little bit later

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321906/lazy-cartesian-product-of-several-seqs-in-scala

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Types like `List[Any]` are most often avoided in Scala – so much of the power of the language comes from its smart type system, and this kind of type impedes this.  So your instinct to turn the list into a normalized `List[List[Int]]` is spot on:

```
val normalizedList = list.map { 
    case x: Int => List(x)
    case list: List[Int @unchecked] => list 
}
```

Note that this will eventually throw a runtime exception if `list` includes a `List` of some type other than `Int`, such as `List[String]`, due to type erasure.  This is exactly the kind of problem that arises when failing to use strong types!   You can read more about strategies for dealing with type erasure [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094173/how-do-i-get-around-type-erasure-on-scala-or-why-cant-i-get-the-type-paramete).

Once you have a normalized `List[List[Int]]`, then you can use `foldLeft` to build the combinations.  You are also correct in seeing that a `for` comprehension can work well here:

```
normalizedList.foldLeft(List(List.empty[Int])) { (acc, next) => 
    for { 
        combo <- acc
        num <- next 
    } yield (combo :+ num) 
}
```

In each iteration of the `foldLeft`, we consider one more sublist (`next`) from the `normalizedList`.  We look at each combination thus far constructed (each `combo` in `acc`), and then for each number `num` in `next`, we make a new combination by appending it to `combo`.

As you might now, `for` comprehensions are really syntactic sugar for `map`, `flatMap`, and `filter` operations.  So we can also express this with those more primitive methods:

```
normalizedList.foldLeft(List(List.empty[Int])) { (acc, next) => 
    acc.flatMap { combo => 
        next.map { num => combo :+ num } 
    } 
}
```

You can even use the (somewhat silly) `:/` alias for `foldLeft`, switch the order of the maps, and use underscore syntax for ultimate brevity:

```
(List(List[Int]()) /: normalizedList) { (acc, next) => next.flatMap { num => acc.map(_ :+ num) } }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val list = List(1,2,
  List(3,4),
  List(5,6,7)
)
def getAllCombinations(list: List[Any]) : List[List[Int]] ={
  //normalize head so it is always a List
  val headList: List[Int] = list.head match {
    case i:Int => List(i)
    case l:List[Int] => l
  }
  if(list.tail.nonEmpty){
    // recursion for tail combinations
    val tailCombinations : List[List[Int]] = getAllCombinations(list.tail)

    //combine head combinations with tail combinations
    headList.flatMap(
      {i:Int => tailCombinations.map(
        {l=>List(i).++(l)}
        )
      }
    )
  }
  else{
    headList.map(List(_))
  }
}
print(getAllCombinations(list))
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with the use of a foldLeft, as well.  In the code below, each item of the outer List is folded into the List of List's by combining each current list with each new item.

```
val list = List(1,2, List(3,4), List(5,6,7) )

val lxl0 = List( List[Int]() )    //start value for foldLeft
val lxl = list.foldLeft( lxl0 )( (lxl, i) => {
    i match {
        case i:Int          => for( l <- lxl ) yield l :+ i
        case newl:List[Int] => for( l <- lxl; 
                                    i <- newl ) yield l :+ i
    }
})

lxl.map( _.mkString(",") ).foreach( println(_))
```

While I didn't use the map that you desired, I do believe that the code may be changed to do the map and make all elements List[Int].  Then, that may simplify the foldLeft to simply do the for-comprehension.  I was not able to get that to work immediately, though ;)